# How do I incorporate an asp:RadioButtonList into an asp:Table, where each radio button inhabits one cell of the table?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html-table, radio-group

So, I am trying to user an asp:RadioButtonList in an asp:Table element. I am needing to repeat the radio buttons into four separate cells for selection by the user. I have been playing around with it for a couple days and just can't figure it out. I included the code I currently have below as well as a picture example of what I am trying to achieve.

[image: Example of how I want it to look]

```
         <asp:Table runat="server" CssClass="table table-sm table-bordered text-center align-items-center">
            <asp:TableHeaderRow>
                <asp:TableHeaderCell>
                    <h5>ExampleText</h5>
                </asp:TableHeaderCell>
                <asp:TableHeaderCell>
                    <asp:Label Text="ExampleText" runat="server" />
                </asp:TableHeaderCell><asp:TableHeaderCell>
                    <asp:Label Text="ExampleText" runat="server" />
                </asp:TableHeaderCell><asp:TableHeaderCell>
                    <asp:Label Text="ExampleText" runat="server" />
                </asp:TableHeaderCell><asp:TableHeaderCell>
                    <asp:Label Text="ExampleText" runat="server" />
                </asp:TableHeaderCell>
            </asp:TableHeaderRow>
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    ExampleText
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="4">
                    <asp:radiobuttonlist runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" >
                        <asp:listitem />
                        <asp:listitem />
                        <asp:listitem />
                        <asp:listitem />
                    </asp:radiobuttonlist>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
```

But this ends up lookging more like this...
[image: How it looks with my current code]

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you drop in a Radiobutton list as a "single" control into a column, then you going to get/have/see a radio button list in that ONE column.

However, you can of course use separate radio button(s), and not a list.

And it turns out you can have those "separate" buttons STILL behave as a group. In other words, grouping the radio buttons means all of the "logic" to select one, but de-select the others STILL works.

So, we would need to have say 5 columns in the table (or better yet gridview), and then use the "group" option to glue them back together.

However, with say 5 options, and 5 seperate buttons? Well, then we kind of don't care about a "value" but ONLY if the RB is checked, or not.

So, say we have a hotel rating from 1 to 5.

Normally, we could have a "value" for each button, and thus set 1-5, or get 1-5.

but, now we have 5 buttons, so we have to write extra code to take the value 1 to 5, and translate into our 5 seperate buttons.

Hence, lets call them R1 to R5, and that keeps this simple.

So, lets drag in a grid view, and THEN add 5 RB's, for the seperate columns:

So, we have this:

```
         <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table" Width="50%">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="Hotel Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="5&nbsp;Star" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <ItemTemplate><asp:RadioButton ID="R1" runat="server"  GroupName="G1"  />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Excellent" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <ItemTemplate><asp:RadioButton ID="R2" runat="server"  GroupName="G1"  />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Good" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <ItemTemplate><asp:RadioButton ID="R3" runat="server"  GroupName="G1"  />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Fair" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <ItemTemplate><asp:RadioButton ID="R4" runat="server"  GroupName="G1"  />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Poor" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <ItemTemplate><asp:RadioButton ID="R5" runat="server"  GroupName="G1"  />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

And our code behind to load up the grid could be this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid()
    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)

        Dim strSQL As String =
            "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName"

        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            Dim rstData = New DataTable
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            GridView1.DataSource = rstData
            GridView1.DataBind()
        End Using

    End Using


End Sub

Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        Dim gData As DataRowView = e.Row.DataItem
        Dim intRating As Integer = gData("Rating")

        If intRating > 0 Then
            Dim strRadioBut As String = "R" & intRating
            Dim RB As RadioButton = e.Row.FindControl(strRadioBut)
            RB.Checked = True
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

so, on row databound, we could have bound JUST the value if this was as single radio button list, but we now have to pluck out WHICH RB to check box based on the hotel rating column (with a value from 1 to 5).

The end result is thus this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was able to create a similar effect (my first picture) I just didn't want to have to create a way to track all of the ID's for every button individually. This is why I was really hopping to use the radio button list, then I just need to track one ID per row. 

Your answer has given me some insight on a way to handle it if I am unable to figure out how to use the radio button list. So, again, thank you for your response!

Comment: You might be able space out and format a rb list,  but it would seem that separate buttons looks to a better choice,  and not much code as a result. A save button outside the gv would require a r1 to r5 loop to get the one choice- a bit more complex,  but not too bad